# Splitting an array into columns

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Expected result is below.  Trying to split old array into 3 arrays. I don't want to "chunk" it but instead want the items put into almost 'columns'

```
var old_array = ["1","2","3","4","5"];
var new_array = new Array();

for(i=0; i<old_array.length; i++)
{
    new_array[i%3].push(old_array[i]);
}
```

The result should be:

```
new_array[0] = [3] 
new_array[1] = [1, 4]
new_array[2] = [2, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

start i at 1 and reference the values as old_array[i - 1]

```
var old_array = ["1","2","3","4","5"];
var new_array = new Array();

for(i = 1; i < old_array.length + 1; i++)
{
    new_array[i%3] = new_array[i%3] || [];
    new_array[i%3].push(old_array[i - 1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not call `new_array[i%3].push`, because `new_array[i%3]` doesn’t exist. You need to initialize those sub-arrays before you can push a value into them for the first time.

And to get the result you want, you need to “shift” the index by one as well:

```
var old_array = ["1","2","3","4","5"];
var new_array = [];

for(i=0, mod_i=0; i<old_array.length; i++)
{
    mod_i = (i+1)%3;
    if(!new_array[mod_i]) {
        new_array[mod_i] = [];
    }
    new_array[mod_i].push(old_array[i]);
}

console.log(new_array);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yjxdjmsa/

Answer (score 0):

```
var old_array      = ["1","2","3","4","5"],
    new_array      = [],
    num_of_columns = 3;   // adjustable

for(var i=0, n=old_array.length; i<n; i++)
{ 

    // 1: turn string into an Int
    var val     = parseInt(old_array[i]);

    // 2: determine column placement
    // change 'val' to 'i' if wanting it by index of old_array (not by value)
    var col_num = val % num_of_columns;

    // 3: create the new column array if it doesn't exist, otherwise use the old one
    var col_arr = new_array[col_num] = new_array[col_num] || [];

    // 4: store the value in the correct column
    col_arr[ col_arr.length ] = val;
}
```

---

Explanation:

1. Your output is showing that you've converted your input as string to a numeric value (no other answer does this conversion)
2. It's unclear if you're grouping the columns by value, or the position they are in your *old_array*, so you'll have to decide, regardless, I've made it a simple change
3. In order to add to an array, an array must exist; simply grab the column array if you've already created it, or create a new blank array to use next time
4. Assign the value; notice the syntax, which should be a little faster than a `.push()` call

Result:

```
new_array[0] = [3] 
new_array[1] = [1, 4]
new_array[2] = [2, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

As a note: in your function, `i` becomes a global variable, not a local one, because you didn't use `var`.

```
var mod = 3;
var old_array = ["1","2","3","4","5"];
var new_array = [];

for (var i = 0; i < mod; i++)
{
    new_array[i] = [];
}

for (var i = 0; i < old_array.length; i++)
{
    new_array[old_array[i] % mod].push(old_array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost there. You just needed to add the subarrays into your new_array

```
var old_array = ["1","2","3","4","5"];
var new_array = [[], [], []]

for(i=0; i<old_array.length; i++)
{
    new_array[i%3].push(old_array[i]);
}
```